# Importing NTFSSecurity module from UNC path fails

Tags: powershell, .net-4.0

I've created a central repository for Powershell modules, but I'm having trouble loading one in particular.  The [NTFSSecurity](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85) module is failing to import with the following message.

```
PS Z:\> Import-Module NTFSSecurity
Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file://\\fs\PowerShellModules\NTFSSecurity\Security2.dll' or one of its
dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
At \\fs\PowerShellModules\NTFSSecurity\NTFSSecurity.Init.ps1:141 char:1
+ Add-Type -Path $PSScriptRoot\Security2.dll
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file://\\fs\PowerShellModules\NTFSSecurity\PrivilegeControl.dll' or one
of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
At \\fs\PowerShellModules\NTFSSecurity\NTFSSecurity.Init.ps1:142 char:1
+ Add-Type -Path $PSScriptRoot\PrivilegeControl.dll -ReferencedAssemblies $PSScrip ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file://\\fs\PowerShellModules\NTFSSecurity\ProcessPrivileges.dll' or one
of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
At \\fs\PowerShellModules\NTFSSecurity\NTFSSecurity.Init.ps1:143 char:1
+ Add-Type -Path $PSScriptRoot\ProcessPrivileges.dll
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Types added
NTFSSecurity Module loaded
Import-Module : Unable to find type [Security2.IdentityReference2]: make sure that the assembly containing this type
is loaded.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module NTFSSecurity
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Security2.IdentityReference2:TypeName) [Import-Module], RuntimeExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I'm running Windows Managment Foundation 3.0 Beta, which includes PowerShell 3.0.  I have a feeling that the new security measures introduced in .NET 4.0 are playing a part in this, but running `Powershell.exe` with the `-version 2.0` switch doesn't fix anything either.  I have modified my **powershell.exe.config** files in both the **system32** and **SysWOW64** folders to the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <loadfromremotesources enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The files are not "blocked", I've checked each one individually (as well as run `Unblock-File` on the directory).  Permissions from the server end are fine, I've verified that I have access to everything.  What have I not checked?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a corrupt file/bad download.

I was receiving the same error when trying to load the module from one of my scripts.  I went and re-downloaded the newer v2.3 and extracted it into my Powershell Modules folder (C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\Modules\NTFSSecurity).

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than load the module directly from a share, I tend to have a function that copies it locally (this can be adjusted to look for newer versions as well). I suppose this could be written in-line, but I made it a function as part of my 'common modules' that I load.

```
Function Import-NTFSModule {
   $NTModule = 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\Modules\NTFSSecurity'
   $NTSource = '\\servername.fqdn\sharename\Modules\NTFSSecurity'
   If (!(Get-Module -Name NTFSSecurity)) {
      If (!(Test-Path -Path $NTModule) -and (Test-Path $NTSource)) { Copy-Item $NTSource -Destination "$NTModule\" -Recurse -Force }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the .ZIP file you download is blocked from being executed.  Right-click it and choose "Unblock" before you unpack it, and the files beneath will be unblocked as well.

Sorry that when I originally posted, I didn't see that you said you had unblocked it.  I only got the error (identical error code) while the files were in a blocked state.

Answer (score -1):

Run the Import-Module NTFSSecurity from **Windows Powershell** (not the **ISE**)

Comment: Please elaborate why you imply the ISE cannot be used to import the module in question, and why you think he's not using the shell.  Looks like a copy/paste from the shell to me.  Also, the copy/paste from 5 years ago runs exactly the command that you recommend.